# When compiling from source, do we git checkout release-v0.17 or latest (currently v0.17.1.9)?

Tags: monerod, linux

In the [docs](https://github.com/monero-project/monero#on-linux-and-macos), we are told to run `git checkout release-v0.17`.

But according to [releases](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/releases/tag/v0.17.1.9), latest release is currently `v0.17.1.9`.

Which one should be checkout?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out... `release-v0.17` for sure (last commit was 13 days ago).

Latest release (currently `v0.17.1.9`) was released on Jan 8 (months ago).